# How to read and display PPS scorecard comments (Annotations) programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint, performancepoint

I have created a scorecard using the Dashboard Designer. My requirement is to display the scorecard comments in a separate Web Part.

So that the user can view the comments without right clicking and going to comments inside the scorecard.

I couldn't find any references online. So any help guys?

Thanks a lot..

Comment: I found this reference.. which give some hits - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/performancepoint/archive/2010/09/13/using-the-ppsauthoringservice-web-service.aspx

Comment: This is how I implemented this..